# Get kth common element from given integer array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I want to find out the kth most common element from an array and I was able to find most common element but I don't know how to find kth common one.

I tried like:

```
 private static int KthCommonElement(int[] a, int k)
 {   
     var counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
     foreach (int number in a)
     {
         int count;
         counts.TryGetValue(number, out count);
         count++;
         //Automatically replaces the entry if it exists;
         //no need to use 'Contains'
         counts[number] = count;
     }
     int mostCommonNumber = 0, occurrences = 0;
     foreach (var pair in counts)
     {
         if (pair.Value > occurrences)
         {
             occurrences = pair.Value;
             mostCommonNumber = pair.Key;
         }
     }
     Console.WriteLine("The most common number is {0} and it appears {1} times", mostCommonNumber, occurrences);

    return mostCommonNumber;
}
```

Comment: How efficient does this have to be? Does it need to be more efficient than a full sort?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can sort the elements by their occurence and take the kth element:

```
int[] orderedByOccurence = a.OrderByDescending(i => counts[i]).ToArray();
if (orderedByOccurence.Length > k)
    Console.WriteLine($"{k}th most common element: {orderedByOccurence[k]});
```

---

But as Adam pointed out in the comments, you can shorten your code by using `GroupBy`:

```
private static int KthCommonElement(int[] a, int k)
{
    if (a == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
    if (a.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException();
    if (k < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    var ordered = a.GroupBy(i => i, (i, o) => new { Value = i, Occurences = o.Count()})
                     .OrderByDescending(g => g.Occurences)
                     .ToArray();

    int index = k;
    if (ordered.Length <= index)   
    {
        // there are less than k distinct values in the source array
        // so add error handling here, either throw an exception or
        // return a "magic value" that indicates an error or return the last element
        index = ordered.Length - 1;
    }

    var result = ordered[index];
    Console.WriteLine("The most common number is {0} and it appears {1} times", 
            result.Value, result.Occurrences);

    return result.Value;
}
```

Comment: There is also a way to do the population of the counts themselves using `GroupBy` if you want to play code golf with it.

Comment: I think need some improvement over here: return ordered[k];

Comment: @DipakAkhade can you be more specific? What kind of improvement?

Comment: @DipakAkhade I updated the answer so that it also outputs the number of occurences of the value as you did in the question.

Comment: I am confused in this answer and not getting right answer. I am getting right answer using your previous answer.

Comment: @DipakAkhade There was a missing `}` at `Occurences = o.Count()`. I fixed it. This is essentialy the same as my previous answer, but instead of taking only the numbers, I take the numbers and the count of their occurences, so you can output that value too.

Comment: Need to improve int index = k-1;

Comment: @DipakAkhade that depends on what you pass as arguments for `k`. Arrays are zero-indexed. From your short comments, I can't deduce what `k` is going to be like. if `index = k-1;` does what you want, then use this.